# Using useDelimiter to divide data from txt file

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop, java.util.scanner, local-variables

I have a data in a text file which is in format:

```
AB-9, Gregson, Brian, R T, Mr
```

I want to divide the up into and store the first one, `AB-9`, in a local variable, I have done all of that but the problem currently is that when I print the value of id, it prints with `,`. How can I get rid of the extra comma?

Another issue is that the first line in the data is not being read.

```
public void readData()
{
 File theNewData = new File("new_data.txt");
        Scanner inputFrom = new Scanner(theNewData);
        while(inputFrom.hasNextLine())
        {
             String lineOftext = inputFrom.nextLine().trim();  
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(lineOftext).useDelimiter(",[ ]*");

                 String id = inputFrom.next();

                 System.out.println(id);
        }

        inputFrom.close();
}
```

Comment: There is no need to create an additional scanner for each line. Just set the delimeter of the outer scanner to your delimeters + `System.lineSeparator()` and use next() and hasNext() methods to go through the input.

Answer (score 0):

Check out String.split()
Details at:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29